# Multiple Sticky Headers - CSS / JavaScript / AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, sticky

I tried to find some solution for the following scenario:

1. Header height is all different
2. Mouse scroll down
3. Fixed headers

Does anyone know how to make multiple sticky headers like this?

(1) init

[image]

(2) scroll down (using mouse)

[image]

(3) scroll down (using mouse)

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? Is there any special reason why you can't use position: fixed with different top attributes?

Comment: are you trying to implement an accordion?

Comment: I tried to like this, but it not fixed header A, B, C... [Multiple Sticky Headers](http://codepen.io/ipelekhan/pen/Gebnf)

Comment: And when you click on a header, the content below is displayed? What's the behaviour of it?

Comment: It's not an accordion, just scroll down using mouse.

Comment: @KeisukeKATO I've updated the answer. it works fine for multiple headers :)

Answer (score 6):

hmm...

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fepuwahutu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var $headers = $(".header");
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (scrollTop <= 0) {
    // reset all
    $headers.css({
      position: "relative",
      top: "0px"
    });
  } else {
    $headers.each(function(index, $el) {

      var $curHeader = $($headers).eq(index);
      var curTop = $curHeader.offset().top;
      var curHeight = $curHeader.height();

      // scroll up
      var isRelative = ($el.isFixed && scrollTop <= $el.exTop);

      // scroll down
      var isFixed = (curTop <= scrollTop);

      var position = "";
      var top = 0;

      if (isRelative) {
        // reset
        positon = "relative";
        top = 0;

        $el.isFixed = false;
      } else if (isFixed) {
        position = "fixed";
        if (0 < index) {
          for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            top += $($headers).eq(i).height();
          }
        }
        scrollTop += curHeight;

        if (!$el.isFixed) {
          $el.isFixed = true;
          $el.exTop = curTop;
        }
      }

      $($el).css({
        position: position,
        top: top + "px"
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 10000px;
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

div.header:nth-child(7) {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>content 0</div>
    <div class="header">header 1</div>
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div class="header">header 2</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div class="header">header 3</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

I'm calculating the height of the headers and setting the `top` property.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/javaxamube/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**

```js
  $(window).scroll(function () {
var $headers = $(".header");
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $headers.each(function (index, el) {
        var height = 0;
        if (index == 0) {
            height = "0px";
        } else {
            for ( var x = index - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                height += $headers.eq(x).height();
            }
        }
        height = height + "px";
        $(el).css({
            "position": "fixed",
                "top": height
        });
    });
} else {
    $headers.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: "0"
    });
}
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 10000px;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.header:first-child {
  height: 20px;
}
div.header:nth-child(5) {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">header 1</div>
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div class="header">header 2</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div class="header">header 3</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yours all appear to collapse/sticky together at once. They are supposed to happen one at a time when each header hits the next one.

Answer (score 1):

With only css
Codepen-[FollowMe Headers](https://codepen.io/danish64/pen/jOpGovv)

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  min-height:200vh;
  border:2px solid;
}
.first {
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  height: 10rem;
}

.second {
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  height: 10rem;
  
}
.third {
  height:50px;
  background:green;
  height: 10rem;
  
}

.stickyContainer {
  .sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 2rem;
    background: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first stickyContainer">
  <div class="sticky"><h1>1</h1></div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
<div class="second stickyContainer">
  <div class="sticky"><h1>2</h1></div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="third stickyContainer">
  <div class="sticky"><h1>3</h1></div>
  <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```